# jQuery & XML mystery get Digits NOT Letters

Tags: jquery, html, xml

**BIG EDIT 11/19/2012**

So, my problem is here.
I'm trying to develop a simple cart app with jQuery and XML.

Everything's OK, but only if the name of My pizz only contains numbers... **WHY ???**

Try yourself, you'll constat that only the "66666" pizza is working... **WHY ???**

[WORKING DEMO HERE](http://bzez.0fees.net/examples/jXML/)

**Here is my jS code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "example.xml", 
  dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
  success: function(xml) {  
   $(xml).find('row').each(function(){
    var Col0 = $(this).find('nompizz').text();
    var Col1 = $(this).find('petit').text();
    var Col2 = $(this).find('moyen').text();
    var Col3 = $(this).find('grand').text();

    $('<tr id="bar"></tr>').html('<th class="title">'+Col0+'</th><td onclick="DisPlay('+Col1+');GetName('+Col0+');">'+Col1+'€</td><td onclick="DisPlay('+Col2+');GetName('+Col0+');">'+Col2+'€</td><td onclick="DisPlay('+Col3+');GetName('+Col0+');">'+Col3+'€</td>').appendTo('#pizzas');

   });
  }
 }); 
});
function DisPlay(Figure) {   
     var Display = document.getElementById('Display');
     if (Figure === null) {
         Display.value = Figure;
     }
     else {
         Display.value += "+"+Figure;
         Screen = Display.value
         result = eval(Screen);

         Display.value =result;
     }

      Figure = null;
}
function GetName(NomPizz) {
      var $newItem = '<li>Ajouté: '+NomPizz+'</li>';
      $('.theList').append($newItem); 
}
```

**And here my XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
 <row>
  <nompizz>66666</nompizz>
  <petit>10</petit >
  <moyen>15</moyen >
  <grand>20</grand>
 </row>
 <row>
  <nompizz>Letters</nompizz >
  <petit>15</petit >
  <moyen>20</moyen >
  <grand>25</grand>
 </row>
</document>
```

Comment: should get in habit of using `var` for all your variable declarations... asking for all sorts of problems if you don't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is that your `GetAnswer()` function is agnostic to the rest of the application.  It doesn't know what was clicked.  I think that the easiest thing to do would be to just add the `nom` parameter to your `DisPlay()` function call.  Like this:  (remove the linefeeds)

```
$('<tr id="bar"></tr>').html('<th class='+Col0+' data-item='+Col0+'>'+Col0+'</th>    <td onclick="DisPlay('+Col1+',\"'+Col0+'\")">'+Col1+'€</td>    <td onclick="DisPlay('+Col2+',\"'+Col0+'\")">'+Col2+'€</td>    <td onclick="DisPlay('+Col3+',\"'+Col0+'\")">'+Col3+'€</td>').appendTo('#pizzas');
```

Then your `DisPlay(Figure)` becomes:

```
function DisPlay(Figure, nom) {
    var Display = document.getElementById('Display');
    if (Figure === null) {
        Display.value = Figure;
    }
    else 
    {
        Display.value += "+"+Figure;

        //instead of this --> //GetAnswer();

        //in your old code you had some of these variables declared as non-global variables, but were using them like they were global variables
        Screen = Display.value.replace(/'/g, ' ');
        result = eval(Screen);   
        Display.value = result;
        $('.theList').append('<li>Ajouté: '+nom+'</li>');
    }
    Figure = null;
}
```

A word about global variables vs. non-global variables.  If you 'var' something inside a function, that variable is local to that function.  It seems like you were mixing and matching your vars.  For more on that [read this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)

EDIT:

After your new edits you are only getting numeric pizza names because you need to have quotes int he proper place.  Try changing all your `GetName('+Col0+');` to `GetName(\''+Col0+'\');`

So that whole line would read:

```
$('<tr id="bar"></tr>').html('<th class="title">'+Col0+'</th><td onclick="DisPlay('+Col1+');GetName(\''+Col0+'\');">'+Col1+'€</td><td onclick="DisPlay('+Col2+');GetName(\''+Col0+'\');">'+Col2+'€</td><td onclick="DisPlay('+Col3+');GetName(\''+Col0+'\');">'+Col3+'€</td>').appendTo('#pizzas');
```

Comment: Thx ! I've ever tried this.. And it's not working... It won't get the "Col0" for "nom" param....

Comment: I believe that with your new code, you need to have quotes.  See my edit.

Comment: It works ! Thx guy ! I'll be more attentive to that quotes ! You rocks !

Comment: @bZezzz - You should probably reward davehale23 with the bounty if he helped you find the solution.

Comment: @MattHuggins if the answer has 2+ upvotes it will get half the bounty anyway :) (not that he shouldn't award it; just saying)

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks for info! It didn't have 2+ upvotes when I first commented though. ;)

Answer (score 1):

actually problem is that your `onclick` function passing string without quotation, put quotation for both `GetName('value')` and `DisPlay('value')` it will solve the problem.

```
<td onclick="DisPlay('"+Col1+"');GetName('"+Col0+"');">'+Col1+'€</td>
```

ISSUE:

if you put string without quotation js will consider it variable and through an error of undefined variable while numbers will work because int does not required any quotation:

eg;
    text

it will execute `DisPlay` and take 15 as int while on executing `GetName(Letter)` it will try to find `Letter` variable which is undefined while `GetName('Letter')` will execute.